# Angular: mat-select, reactive form, disable does not show dotted line

Tags: angular, angular-material

When using mat-select with a reactive form, setting it to disabled does not show a dotted line as shown in an example [here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) but a continuous line.

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <mat-form-field fxFlex="100%" >
    <mat-select formControlName="tags" placeholder="Select tags" name="tags"></mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

component.ts:

```
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    tags: [{value: '', disabled: true},],
  });
}
```

This also happens when I have this:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  tags: ['',],
});

this.myForm.controls.tags.disable();
```

or this:

```
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    tags: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true},),
  });
}
```

or this:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  tags: new FormControl('',),
});

this.myForm.get('tags').disable()
```

I am using Angular 7.2.6

What is the correct way to do this to get the dotted line?

Comment: I am getting a dotted line with your code

Comment: I think that it's not possible create a control disabled using FormBuilder, the way to use disable() try `this.myForm.get('tags').disable()`, using new FormControl, you can do it

Comment: @GangadharGandi What Angular version are you using?

Comment: @Eliseo I tried that with the same results. I updated the question.

Comment: @Bastian, must be work. A little example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcmza1?file=src/app/input-overview-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the soluction. It was actually because I had the following in the css:

```
.mat-form-field-underline {
  color: #673ab7 !important;
  background-color: #673ab7 !important;
}
```

I wanted to be the underline of that color also if the field was not active but that does not seem to work with the disabled fields as a continuous line gets drawn.

So for now, the not ideal solution is to put this in the css:

```
.mat-form-field-underline {
  color: #673ab7 !important;
}
```

So the underline is at least in the color I want when the field is active. But I could not find any solution to make it work with the inactive and disabled underline.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    tags:  first: new FormControl({value: value, disabled: true},)
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried that with the same results. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Angular 8:

```js
tags: this.fb.group({
    id: this.fb.control({value: '', disabled: true}),
    name: this.fb.control(''),
    label: this.fb.control('')
})
```

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" formGroupName="tags">
    <mat-label>Tag</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="id">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of tags"
                    [value]="tag.id">
            {{tag.label}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation for your answer.